# how can i get this variable in the "then"?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, arp, nt

i take data from firebase , there are datas but i can't access to variable.
Can you help me please ?
Thank you in advance.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Models {
  var data;
  Map jsondata;

  Future<Map<dynamic,dynamic>> where() async{
    await Firestore.instance
    .collection('musteri')
    .where("name", isEqualTo: "Lion")
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.map( (DocumentSnapshot document) {
            this.jsondata = document.data;
            print(this.jsondata);
           // There is data here. when i use print(this.jsondata); , data apper in the terminal.
        }).toString(),
      );

      print(this.jsondata); // this is an empty data.

    return jsondata;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note is that when you are running a Firebase Query, the response type you will get is of a `QuerySnapshot`, which can be easier to understand if you think of them as a `List` of `DocumentSnapshot`s.

So you can rephrase your code like this

```dart
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('musteri')
    .where("name", isEqualTo: "Lion")
    .getDocuments();
```

Now, once you have the query snapshot, you can iterate through it and get the `DocumentSnapshot` you want.

```dart
snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
  jsondata = document.data;
});
```

And then you can return the `jsondata`. But keep in mind that this `jsondata` will be the last element in the `QuerySnapshot`.

So I think you will also need to rephrase your method to return a `List<Map<String, String>>` instead of a `Map<String, String>`

Overall, your function would look like this

```dart
Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> where() async {

  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('musteri')
      .where("name", isEqualTo: "Lion")
      .getDocuments();

  snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
    jsondata = document.data;
  });

  return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you for your help.